# get the current item position from view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I tried the infinite view pager from [this link](https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager). I would like to know that how can I get the current item position according to this coding. I retrieve position from viewPager's `getCurrentItem` method. But the position is incorrect. I have tried the callback `OnPageChangeListener` method but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: vp.getCurrentItem() where vp is view-pager.post some code so that i can help.

Comment: I got the position index from `onPageSelected` method and find by this position from array. I got exception because the position index is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

            switch (arg0) {
            case 1:

                fragment1 = (Fragment1) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(
                        "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":"
                                + (arg0 - 1));
                Bundle bundle =fragment1.SaveComplaintData();
                if(bundle.size()==0){
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                }
                else{
                data.setBundle(bundle);
                }
                break;

            case 2:

                fragment2 = (fragment2) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(
                        "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":"
                                + (arg0 - 1));


                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            btnAction(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }

    });
```

Comment: I would like to get current item position.

Comment: I did as ur coding. But I got null fragment. I cannot find fragment.

Answer (score 0):

This displays current page of viewpager while horizontally moving screen.

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int currentPage = viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1;
                textView.setText(currentPage + " out of " + ...);
            }

            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int currentPage = viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1;
                textView.setText(currentPage + " out of " + ...);

            }
        });
```

instead of `...` you can put the total number of pages from current item.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain what you're posting?

Comment: it display current page of viewpager while horizontally moving screen.

Comment: instead of "..." you can put the total number of pages from current item.